# ubuntu 16.04 home folder shows hidden directories

Tags: home-directory, hidden-files

Home folder DEFAULTS to showing hidden files.
CTR-H does toggle between showing hidden files and not.
But I prefer to NOT have them show in default.
Is there a different version that looks more like 14 to show folder options?

Comment: And simply "undo it"

Answer (score 1):

Ỳou can try to uncheck it on menu **Edit** >> **Preferences** >> **Show hidden files**.